# Custom icon not showing in Pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, icons, pyinstaller

Using PyInstaller, the icon works fine, just a small problem i cannot solve.

Whether ***Tkinter*** app or ***console*** app, if I make an executable file with a custom icon the default python one still shows in some case... It works fine on everything except on **Details View Layout** (OS folder option). I do not know how to fix this or why this happens. Any suggestions or help to fix this small issue?

I tried google search but no results, or maybe I did not search using the right words.

***Platform tested**: Windows 10 and 7*

Comment: Could you please share your code or your .spec file? Thanks!

Comment: I do not think is from my code or spec file... Maybe the icon required there a smaller size and that ico files have not a required size... I will try to make smaller size next time and if is this the solve solution I will come back with an answer